# shrinking flexboxes to the same height of the shortest box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have a flexbox layout that looks like this:

[image]

The blue is class = "wrap", the orange and all three yellow boxes are contained in two separate class = "wrap_col", and each yellow box is contained in class = "wrap_item".

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap_col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.wrap_item {
  margin:10px;
  display: flex;
  flex:1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column; 
}
```

How can I shrink the three yellow boxes' heights down so that it is the same height as the orange box?  Can you shrink flexboxes down to the same height as the shortest box?

[image]

Comment: What's creating the space in both sets of boxes? You should post your markup, too, and give a working example of the current layout that you're trying to change.

Comment: Question was marked as a duplicate, so I can't provide an answer.  Here's a fiddle I put together to address your specific code: https://jsfiddle.net/euqjxxr9/. My guess is that you have height explicitly set on the items.  The linked version is a completely relative one where the height is set in one place (the `.wrap` element)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this would be to make sure that the height of both your columns with the `.wrap-col` class is this same (either set a fixed height or set `height: 100%` and have them both fill the space of the `.wrap` element). Then make sure `flex-shrink: 1` is set for all flex items to.

```
.wrap_item {
  margin:10px;
  display: flex;
  flex:1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column; 
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dylanstark/jdxstyxv/). Try changing the height of the `.wrap` element and you can see the boxes resizing to fit.

Comment: Thanks Dylan and @joseph, so do i NEED to set a height for class wrap in order to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Dave, yes in order for the flex-box to shrink the containing flex items, the box itself has to have height set in one way or another. Without a set height the flexbox has no reason to try to shrink or grow its internal items to match its height, it just leaves the items as they would normally render.

Comment: You don't need a set height for the wrap but I don't know if this matches your needs since I don't know what you're using to size the boxes. https://jsfiddle.net/jdxstyxv/1/

Comment: Hi @Alejalapeno did you mean to link to the fiddle that I just created specifically to answer this question?

Comment: It's modified. You'll notice the wrapper does not have a height.

Comment: @Alejalapeno ah sorry, I see that it is edited now. Yes you are right that my fiddle doesn't need an implicit height on the wrap! Flex-box can work with the height of the `.big` div which I set as a fixed 600px but the OP hadn't indicated a set height on any flex items or boxes in his question.